# python geocoder fails with django

Tags: python, django, google-maps-api-3, postman

This is so confusing, I have in my jupyter notebook:

```
import geocoder
geocoder.google('94704')
```

receiving:

```
<[OK] Google - Geocode [Berkeley, CA 94704, USA]>
```

Then this is part of a backend code, so I put this in my django project, and run it on the local server, and in postman i POST a JSON with the same argumen, 94704 and I am getting:
[image]

This is the code just in case:

```
def get_county(data):
    """Takes the data in the above format, returns the string of the county name"""
    if data['type']=='zip':
        postal = data['data']
        g = geocoder.google(postal)
    elif data['type']=='geo':
        lat,lon = data['data']
        g = geocoder.google([lat,lon], method='reverse')
    return ' '.join(g.county.split()[:-1])
```

Any ideas?